# Is it required to put engines and buildpack in a nodejs aws lambda application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, buildpack

I'm not sure what is the best practice when it comes to AWS lambdas. I have a node 14 lambda that has been running on server successfully. I use terraform to initialize and maintain the code. Do I need to add node engines specifically and buildpacks? It runs fine without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, buildpacks are not required for using Lambda.

It is possible use [AWS Code build to create container images](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/creating-container-images-with-cloud-native-buildpacks-using-aws-codebuild-and-aws-codepipeline/) using [buildpacks](https://github.com/jkutner/aws-lambda-buildpack), and shipping them to the Lambda container runtime. But that is an optional, and not well-paved path.